# Jasmines is a JavaScript test API or test runner?

Tags: jasmine

I have a confusion with Jasmine. **This is API or runner**?

If it's API, i will use to write automatic test code.

If it's test runner, what kind of test application can be deployed?

Sorry if i miss any information!

Comment: This is API, KarmaJS and MochaJS are tests runners. AssertJS, ExpectJS are assertion libraries.
Jasmine is something in the middle - it provides interface for BDD (describe, it, beforeEach, afterEach) and expresison for assertions (equal, toHaveBeenCalled).

Comment: Thank you. When i install (npm install -g jasmine), i saw that npm download jasmine.cmd, jasmine into ...\AppData\Roaming\npm folder. => So i think maybe Jasmine is runner, too. Is that right?

Comment: What is responsibility of runner? Fetching all files from some directory and fire tests on it? Jasmine doesn't have functionality for traversing folders and fetch files - KarmaJS is responsible for that task.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand.